# what happens when you get an element in a list that does not exist?

Tags: java

I'm trying to get some clarification on what what happens when you try to retrieve and element in an index that does not exist.

```
List<List<Integer>> triangle = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

    //first row is always 1 and only 1
    triangle.add(new ArrayList<>());
    triangle.get(0).add(1);
    
    //loop through the numbers of rows and add them previous rows
    for(int rowNums = 1; rowNums < numRows; rowNums++){
        //creating new row
        List<Integer> row = new ArrayList<>();

        //previous row, used to add
        List<Integer> prevRow = triangle.get(rowNums - 1);

        //first element in the pascal triangle is 1
        row.add(1);

        for(int i = 1; i < rowNums; i++){
            row.add(prevRow.get(i - 1) + prevRow.get(i));

        }
        //last element in a pascal triangle is always 1
        row.add(1);

        //add the row to the triangle list
        triangle.add(row);
    }
    
    return triangle;
```

This code solves a pascal triangle, however, I'm confused at the nested for loop. I know that it looks at the previous rows and add the two elements together. But let say I'm in row 1, I would look back at the previous row (which is 0) and add elements at index 0 and 1 together. but index 1 does not exist in row 0. I hope this is clear.

Comment: In Java, when you access an item that doesn't exist (for instance, by index), you will get an exception. Probably, `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1`.

Comment: why don't you just try it? It won't break your PC, I promise.